# django log in authentication

Tags: django

So I have two apps in my project. One is a normal app doing something, the second one is a log in app where I followed a tutorial on how to set up a user authentication using http://blog.narenarya.in/right-way-django-authentication.html

I am able to implement what was on the website and have gotten the log in page to work, but when I go back to my first app and try to get the logged in user's information with

```
<a>Hello {{ user.username }} </a>,
```

the user name doesn't show up.

How do I connect the two apps so I know the user is logged in when I'm playing around in my first app??

my views.py for my first app looks something like this

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def index(request):
    class RequiredFormSet(BaseFormSet):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(RequiredFormSet, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            for form in self.forms:
                form.empty_permitted = False
     TodoItemFormSet = formset_factory(TodoItemForm, max_num=10, formset=RequiredFormSet)
......
```

templates in settings.py looks like this:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: Every app can be registered in INSTALLED_APPS. But you have better to learn django before you do it :https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: Please show the view from your first app.

Comment: In your `views.py` you either need to pass `user` as a context variable, or do `<a>Hello {{ request.user.username }} </a>`

Comment: i have added views.py of the first app. I tried  
    <a>Hello {{ request.user.username }} </a> 
but it didn't help. 
I have @login_required in my first app's views.py and it does log in and allow me to go to that index page, but i can't get the user's information.
how do i pass user as a context variable?? thanks for all you inputs

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the template context processors installed in your settings?
    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    ...
    )